VB.NET 2019 - Asignar nombre en aplicaciones de inicio W10
Como puedo asignar un nombre de mi aplicación, para que aparezca en el inicio de aplicaciones en Windows 10/11?
Actualmente aparece con un nombre codificado "07C3D04B28CAC208F458C" y no el asignado en el proyecto "Backup"

